# How to put <ng-click> in string in Endpoint.java and send this string back to client side?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, websocket, endpoint

I'm working on a `Chat application` that deliver messages between logged in users in `Web Socket protocol`. On the message that some user send to chat with others, I want to add to it some design so one could have an option to reply to it. I tried to nest to the link `reply` for this message and the `angular` tag `ng-click` in it which will open a `modal reply` for the user (like below).

The content of `ng-click` is a function that gets as an input the message id that the user want to reply to.

My problem is that when clicking `reply` the reply modal is opened for the user but this function is never called!

Here is my code in `ChatEndPoint.java`:

```
String m="<div>
             <div>" + 
                 _content 
          + "</div>  &nbsp; 
             <a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#replyModal'
              ng-click='storemsgid("+_msgid+")'><small>reply</small></a>
          </div> ";
```

Notes:

- `_content` have a String value and `_msgid` have an Integer value.
- `_content` appears in the chat console.
- In the  in HTML page there is a function `storemsgid(id)` and it works(trust me it is not what causes the problem :) ).
- The new message will be inserted in chat console (which is `div` tag) and this one have its own `ng-controller` and it contains the function `storemsgid(id)`.

Please help me or direct me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ng-bind-html directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) to insert HTML from a controller:

```
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myVm as vm">
    <h1>Binding a click handler to AngularJS</h1>
    <p>{{vm.rawMsg}}</p>

    <div ng-bind-html="vm.msg"></div>

  </body>
```

JS:

```
app.controller("myVm", function($sce) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.rawMsg = '<button onclick="angular.element(this).scope().vm.alert(99)">Alert 99</button>'
  vm.msg = $sce.trustAsHtml(vm.rawMsg);

  vm.alert = (x) => alert(x);
})
```

The `ng-bind-html` directive does not compile AngularJS directives such as `ng-click`. Instead use the [onclick attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers) and [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) to invoke the scope function:

```
<button onclick="angular.element(this).scope().vm.alert(99)">
   Alert 99
</button>
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/cT2VBiipiEq5Dq9UGazL?p=preview).